# How to change default directory when adding new attachment in Thunderbird

Tags: linux, thunderbird

Let's say I start a new mail, and I add attachment. By default Thunderbird shows Documents sub-directory from my home directory. But this does not suit me and I would like to change this default directory for good.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Its a little bit funny: you need to set your desired folder in Settings -> Attachments -> Reception !

The same folder will be opened when you try to add the attachment !

Comment: Thank you. What client do you use? Me -- Linux version, 17.x. And I have such tab as Attachment, and then option to "ask when saving" or pointing out fixed folder where to save. So I set it to my home directory, however, when composing new mail I still get documents folder by default.

Comment: I have Windows 8, to use Ubuntu I need to re-boot my machine ...